# This code is not opening an image from my app to system image Viewer

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview

I'm trying to open an image of .jpg extension from my app to default image viewer but Intent is directed to gallery instead of opening image. But the same image is opened from gallery

```
private void openFile() {
        final Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, Paths.Constants.AUTHORITY_APP, new File(Paths.DATA_FOLDER+"/"+ "collage"));
        context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), data, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://"+data.getPath()), "image/*")
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: setDataAndType(data, "image/*"); And i wonder what you consider to be 'opening'.

Comment: You can remove the grand uri permission call.

Comment: What is the name of your image file? I see no file name.

Comment: What do you consider to be 'the system image viewer'?

Comment: Why are you declaring those variables final?

Comment: Thanks Dude... issue is resolved by giving file name to FileProvider